# Are registered users still "audited" with captchas?

Tags: support, spam, user-accounts

I had asked a question earlier, and when I clicked the button to publish the question on the site, I had been hit with a captcha "in order to make sure I'm not a robot."

A couple thoughts about why I think this may have popped up:

- I'm in a different location: I live in Toronto, which is also the location that I list in my profile. However, I am currently in the moment in Kristiansund, Norway. This is strange, because I have also made posts to this site during my visit in Norway (albeit in different towns such as Drammen, Norway), and I have not encountered the captchas at that time.
- Note, I had 2, 406 reputation points at the time of the question writing.
- I was also signed in, and active particularly on chat before writing the question.
- The question was not copy pasted into the box, which Free Radical suggested could've been a reason.

Here is a screenshot showing the captcha:

[image: Human Verification Dialog]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more the system trusts you, the fewer captchas you get. Anonymous visitors get one as soon as they search for something. As soon as you have an account with a few reputation points, captchas are reduced, but they don't disappear. The rules for captchas aren't publicized, but there are two common situations where even high-reputation users will be hit:

- If you start typing an answer, leave it alone for a long time, and finally complete it and post, you'll get a captcha. (I think what happens is that your browser requests a token when you start typing, and when you post, the server checks the age of this token. If the token has expired by the time you post, your browser gets a new one and posts immediately, so you get a captcha because the server thinks you wrote the answer in an instant.) I don't remember hitting that with questions, but that may just be because I ask fewer questions than I answer.
- If you do many things too quickly, you may get a catpcha. I've had captchas as a moderator when I made some quick repetitive actions.

Comment: Alright. Thanks! That makes sense :)